# Can juices fulfill requirement of water ?

Tags: water, juice

As our body needs more water and I drink more juices than water. So, I want to ask that can juices fulfill requirement of water ?  ?

Comment: what do you men by "powered juice", 
the best juice is the one that you make at home with your juicer, and usually it's without any added water

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with getting your daily requirement of water solely from juices, is that most juices have significant amounts of sugar in them. Let's say your favorite juice is orange juice. Orange juice is about 88.3% water so in order to get your recommended 64 fl. oz. (1.892 L) of water you'd have to consume 72 fl. oz. (2.129 L) of juice. Orange juice has 112 Calories in 1 cup (248 g), so you'd have to drink nine cups which would be 1,008 Calories. Add that to whatever food you eat and you'd have a whole helluva lot of calories. Unless you led a very active live style, you'd gain a lot of weight. But as far as water goes, your body really doesn't care where the H<sub>2</sub>O comes from. If you got it from juice or plain water, you'd more or less remain just as hydrated. (I say "more or less" because variations in sodium content of one juice to another would affect how much water your body retains.)
**Edit:** Contents of orange juice came from this [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orange_juice).
**Edit 2:** For those who consider Wikipedia an unreliable source: [this site](http://nutritiondata.self.com/facts/fruits-and-fruit-juices/1971/2) also has similar data.

Comment: Wikipedia is not considered a reliable source, but a quick google search should give you some good results.

Comment: Reference was added. I did not include this in my original answer, as I thought references concerning the contents of orange juice were pretty much readily available.

Comment: @Narusan, what!? I see participants in many Stack Exchange communities using Wikipedia articles as reference sources. It's not as if the contents of orange juice are a big esoteric secret.

Comment: @Narusan, nope.

Comment: Actually, there has been a [Meta Discussion](https://health.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/184/is-wikipedia-a-reliable-source) about Wikipedia, and it concluded that Wikipedia is not suitable to support the main claims of your answer but it's okay to link to a Wikipedia article so that other users understand terminology you are using. I think that this supports my position. The answers there also say that if there is **any** source for the claim, cite it. Only if there is no other source, then you can turn to Wikipedia.

Comment: I used Wikipedia to cite nutritional information, not medical. The two things are different.